# Ionic Framework 3: Splitting a long article page into small pages

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I currently have a long article, almost a short book, which I'm trying to split into sub-pages. Currently I have the overview page, which links to all parts of the article and interlinking between the pages.

**What I have:**
Article which is split into 10 static pages: `page1.html, page2.html, ... , page10.html`

I created 10 pages using `ionic g page page_n` and the overview page `ionic g page Overview` will link to all parts of the article (kind of like a book).

In the `OverviewPage.ts` has methods which link to individual parts.

```
  # run import of all 10 pages

  GoToPage1() {
    this.navCtrl.push(Page1);
  }
  GoToPage2() {
    this.navCtrl.push(Page2);
  }
```

and so on. Each `Page.ts` will have similar methods to link to next and previous pages.

However, this structure seems to be inefficient: if a user goes through the overview goes to reads page 1, then page 2, then page 3 and decides to click on the back button in the navigation, (instead of going straight back to the overview, the user is taken to page 2, then back to page 1 and so on).

Instead, I can approach the problem by defining a details page (so I will only need to create 2 pages in total: overview and detail) which will load these parts dynamically, depends on the parameter passed from the overview page, and load the appropriate HTML page file.

**Question:** I don't really know how to approach this problem, and any solution is appreciated.

P.S. I'm very new to Ionic

Comment: would `this.navCtrl.first()` be what you want? do you always want to go back to the same overview page? if so..use `setRoot()` and you can use `goToRoot()` to get back to it...that way the overview page (`setRoot`) only has to load once. im not sure if this is what you are trying to do.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Instead of pages, you could just use slides...

Comment: @ewizard I'm not sure, but if I setRoot(OverviewPage) on all 10 pages, will the back button in the navigation link to the overview page? I tried adding the following
    this.nav.setRoot(OverviewPage);
    this.nav.popToRoot(); but 1) I don't know where to add it 2) If I add it in the method GoToPage(), the back button in the navigation still doesnt go to the main overview page.

Comment: @sebaferreras After reading https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/ , it sounds something that could work; would it be possible to replace the navigation titles for each slide? Is there a tutorial that you'd recommend reading?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to use Slides for this situation.

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>page 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>page 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>page 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

You can either slide by moving the screen or using button with this method:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
  }
}
```

For more information here's the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/)

Comment: Thanks, I just finished this setup, and I realised that I can't seem to be able to scroll the content, which is on sliders. So If I have multiple paragraphs, I won't be able to scroll down to see the bottom. Could you help me out?

Comment: @Roma yes there is an issue when you both slide and scroll. So do you really need to scroll? Can't you just put one paragraph per slide ?

Comment: I can't, because otherwise I will need 100+ pages/slides which is annoying. This is why I have the overview. The slides had overflow: hidden , which I removed, and now able to scroll. However, 1 more issue, is how to jump from overview page, to slide number 5 for example? I defined a function:   goToSlide(n) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ChapterPage);
    this.slides.slideTo(n);
  } , which 1st goes to the page containing the slides and then I think should go to slide number (n). But this doesn't actually work.

Comment: Ideally what I wanted is to create a details page, which will simply load an html file contents in the <ion-content> tags. Similar to php/python include(). I have these pages separated in html files already e.g. part1.html , part2.html and so on

Comment: I really wouldn't advice doing that. It's better to create a array (book) of strings(paragraphs) & then targeting the paragraph with book[1] book[5] & go on.

Comment: It just seems very manual if I need to put all paragraphs into this array. Plus there are also <li>, <ul> and <divs> in the contents. The total length is 1000+ lines (of the book).

Comment: you can do that with a json file that contains all the paragraphs. Then you use http.get to get the value of that json in a variable. After that you split method to split the book into array of paragraphs. Then all you need is to use the ngfor method on ion <ion-slides>
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let paragraph of book">
    <p>paragraph</p>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>